# Linq To SQL: Retain list order when using .Contains

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I'm using Lucene.net to build a `MyListOfIds As List(Of Integer)` which I then pass on to my Linq service. I then search the database as follows

```
Return _EventRepository.Read().Where(Function(e) MyListOfIds.Contains(e.ID)).ToList
```

Now I know that Lucene is already ordering `MyListOfIds` based on the weight it gave each term. What sucks is that Linq is losing that order in it's SQL search.

My Question: **How can I retain that sort order when building my Lambda expression?**

I tried using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see how the query is being built, but because I had to declare a variable [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) didn't show me the resultant SQL :-(

Here's what I tried in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
Dim i As New List(Of Integer)
i.Add(1)
i.Add(100)
i.Add(15)
i.Add(3)
i.Add(123)

Dim r = (From e In Events
         Where i.Contains(e.ID)
         Select e)
```

*note: my example is in VB.NET, but I don't mind if responses are in C#*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hangy mentioned, I think the Dictionary method is the way to go. I'd go about it this way:

```
Public Function GetLuceneSearchResults(ByVal ids As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Domain.Event) Implements IEventService.GetLuceneSearchResults
    Dim Results = (From e In _EventRepository.Read()
                   Where ids.Contains(e.ID)
                   Select e).ToDictionary(Function(e) e.ID, Function(e) e)

    Return (From i In ids
            Where Results.ContainsKey(i)
            Select Results(i)).ToList()
End Function
```

The first query returns a Dictionary with the event id as key, and the event itself as a value. You get the performance benefit of a hash lookup this way.

Comment: I'm gonna run this through [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) and compare it against my method.

Comment: Ok, that's impressive. I ran your method through DotTrace twice and I ran mine through DotTrace twice, each with exactly the same query, and each returning exactly the same results. Yours ran in 45ms and 15ms, where mine ran in 75ms and 80ms. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome :) The main difference between mine and yours is with the dictionary. Since that's using a hash lookup, the return query only ever needs to iterate once for each number in the ids list while it checks against the Results query. The way you had it, you had to iterate (id ^ 2) times. So if you had 5 ids, your old version would have to iterate through everything 25 times, while with the dictionary you only have to iterate 5 times. I'm sure someone else could explain that better, lol.

Comment: I actually did not anticipate the dictionary method performing that much better when working with those few items. This is why it is always a good idea to compare the different possibilities with a benchmark. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the LINQ to SQL query will return the data in the database's natural order (probably primary key?), because an `IN` condition in SQL (which is what the `.Contains` should be translated to) does not specify any `ORDER` and neither does your LINQ expression. If you think of it as in a normal SQL statement, it becomes obvious that you cannot specify the order in that way easily.

In order to sort the loaded data, you could  get it unsorted and then sort the enumeration by the known order from Lucene. You will probably have to write that on your own (ie. a customer `IComparer<T>`) though.

Answer (score 2):

Get unordered results back from the L2S query, then reorder in the same order as the List in a L2O (linq-to-objects) query using [the .Select overload that gives ordinal position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx). E.g.:

```
var someResult = _EventRepository.Read().Where(e => MyListOfIds.Contains(e.ID)).ToList();

var someResultOrdered =
  from sr in someResult
  join lid in MyListOfIds.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }) on sr.ID equals lid.v
  orderby lid.i
  select sr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to have an IDictionary and your key would be just a incremental (like an identity column) and the value your actual id from Lucene.

Then, in your LINQ2SQL statement instead of doing this "where" clause you can do a "join" in the Dictionary Value with the Column in your DB. In your LINQ, sort by the dictionary key.

**EDIT: ADDED EXAMPLE**

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var ids = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            //key is just a sort sequence, value is the ID from Lucene
            ids.Add(1, 27);
            ids.Add(2, 25);
            ids.Add(3, 29);

            var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var tabs = (from t in ctx.Tabs
                         where ids.Values.Contains(t.TabID)
                         select t).ToList();


            var sorted = from t in tabs
                         join id in ids on t.TabID equals id.Value
                         orderby id.Key
                         select t;

            foreach (var sortedItem in sorted) {
                Console.WriteLine(sortedItem.TabID);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Though this is probably a great idea, I'm not well versed enough in LINQ and JOINS to even begin to try and figure it out.... is that bad :-s

Comment: let me try it out :) I had the same problem at our system. SQL retrieves records randomly if you don't specify an order by (randomly = whatever the performance is best). But in our system since I'm heavily using caching I just did one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you see the answer I posted? What are your thoughts on that approach VS yours when it comes to performance?

Comment: You cannot mix the outside Dictionary join with LINQ. Doing the ToList() will use a LINQ to objects on the 2nd query instead of Linq2SQL

Comment: For you just the 2nd query LINQ statement should be enough since it's a Lucene object and not LINQ2SQL.

Answer (score 1):

#### OP Answer

@hangy got me thinking along the right lines, I think.  Here's what I came up with...

open to suggestions!

```
    Public Function GetLuceneSearchResults(ByVal ids As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Domain.Event) Implements IEventService.GetLuceneSearchResults
        Dim Results = _EventRepository.Read().Where(Function(e) ids.Contains(e.ID)).AsQueryable
        Dim Output As New List(Of Domain.Event)

        For Each i In ids
            Output.Add(Results.Where(Function(e) e.ID = i).SingleOrDefault)
        Next

        Return Output
    End Function
```

Now performance speculation aside, this is definitely working exactly as expected.  I'd love to hear your thoughts on performance enhancements, or if this is just way out to lunch. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this will be a huge performance hit, because Lucene is only sending 5 ID's down to the service, so I'm only ever dealing with a maximum of 5 records in that `For Each` loop.

Comment: If you know that there will never be thousand of entries, that should just work fine. I guess you are right about that not being a performance hit. You could probably create a dictionary of the results (.ToDictionary extension method) and the key being the e.ID. But if you always only get 5 ids from Lucene, the dictionary version could actually be slower. ;) Could be worth a benchmark if you really need it.

Comment: Yes my site only ever allows 5 results per page, and Lucene is doing the calculations when it comes to page number, etc.  The event service will absolutely only be dealing with the final 5 results that are being sent to the View (page).